# Sticky footer not working with full width slider

Tags: html, css

I'm using this code: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html to stick my footer.

Well, as you can see here: http://alsite.com.br/prime/

my `#main` div is passing behind my footer (yellow and blue) part...

What's wrong??

My code:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap"> 
    <div id="header">
        <header>
            <div id="wrap_header">
                <h1 id="logo"><a href="#">Prime Consultoria</a></h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Conheça a Prime</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Produtos e Serviços</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Área do Cliente</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>

    <div id="banner">
        <div id="cbp-fwslider" class="cbp-fwslider">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="banners/banner_1.jpg" alt="img01"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="banners/banner_2.jpg" alt="img02"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="banners/banner_3.jpg" alt="img03"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="banners/banner_4.jpg" alt="img04"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="banners/banner_5.jpg" alt="img05"/></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #wrap {height: 100%;}
body > #wrap {height: auto; min-height: 100%;}
#main { padding-bottom: 160px;}  /* deve ter a mesma altura do rodapé */
#footer {position: relative; margin-top: -160px; height: 160px; clear:both;} /* valor negativo da altura do rodapé */
/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;/
}


#header {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; min-width:100%; height:150px; z-index:1;}
header{ min-width:100%; height:150px; background:url(../imagens/fundo_header_logo.png) top center no-repeat;}

#wrap_header{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#wrap_header #logo{
    float:left;
    padding-top:31px;
    padding-left:15px;
}
#wrap_header #logo a{
    display:block;
    width:224px;
    height:56px;
    background:url(../imagens/logo.png);
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

nav {
    float:right;
 }


#banner{
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    z-index:0;
}

#main{
    position:relative;
    width:950px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:5px solid #f0f0f0;
    background:#FFF;
}
```

BANNER CSS:

```
.cbp-fwslider {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 40px 0 0px;
}

.cbp-fwslider ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.cbp-fwslider ul li {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.cbp-fwslider ul li > a,
.cbp-fwslider ul li > div {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
}

.cbp-fwslider ul li > a img {
    border: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.cbp-fwslider nav span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url(../imagens/sprite.png) -65px 0 no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -50px;
    line-height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.cbp-fwslider nav span:hover {
    background: #378fc3;
}

.cbp-fwslider nav span.cbp-fwnext {
    right: 10px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background: url(../imagens/sprite.png) -65px 0 no-repeat;
}

.cbp-fwslider nav span.cbp-fwprev {
    left: 10px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background: url(../imagens/sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.cbp-fwslider nav span.cbp-fwprev:hover{
    background: url(../imagens/sprite.png) 0 -60px no-repeat;
}
.cbp-fwslider nav span.cbp-fwnext:hover{
    background: url(../imagens/sprite.png) -65px -60px no-repeat;
}

.cbp-fwdots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display:none;
}

.cbp-fwdots span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cbp-fwdots span:hover {
    background: #999;
}

.cbp-fwdots span.cbp-fwcurrent {
    background: #47a3da;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #47a3da;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: You should post your question with the code attached so users in the future can understand the question in case that site goes down.

Comment: Sure..i forget that..

Comment: Can't really be bothered to look at the code, but maybe set a padding-bot or margin-bot to tour #main div eaqual or bigger to the height of the footer? That way it will always remain visible, even if you scroll to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `margin-top: -160px;` on you #footer

Remove that and your #main div will not pass under the footer.

Comment: but this is on the stick footer example.. maybe work whithout that?

Comment: Yep, remove that `margin-top: -160px;` on your `#footer`.